# Awk pattern matching: looping through occurrences, appending text

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am looping through station names within a text file. For each station block within the text file I want to match the first occurrence of "add" and append a close statement using the appropriate sensor and time information from that station block. IF a second sensor exists for that station, I also want to append a close statement after what would be the second occurrence of "add" using it's appropriate sensor and the same time information. If a second sensor doesn't exist it can move onto the next station. I would like to follow this pattern throughout each of the station blocks within a text file. I've tried a few things with awk and sed, but I have only been able to add the close statements after each occurrence of "add". Can anyone guide me towards a more appropriate technique? Here's two example station blocks within the text file:

```
 sta charlie 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43 topico
 time 01/14/2015 23:05:38
 net XI SPREE
 datalogger q330 0100000EA9C2B9C3 # 2842
 sensor cmg3t 0 T3S82
 add

 sensor trillium 0 T3N04
 add
 #######Next station block###############

 sta charlie2 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43 topico2
 time 01/14/2015 23:05:38
 net XI SPREE
 datalogger q330 0100000EA9C2B9C3 # 2842
 sensor trillium 0 T3S84
 add

 sensor sts2 0 T3N04
 add
```

I would like the code to output the following:

```
 sta charlie 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43 topico
 time 01/14/2015 23:05:38
 net XI SPREE
 datalogger q330 0100000EA9C2B9C3 # 2842
 sensor cmg3t 0 T3S82
 add
 close sensor cmg3t 01/14/2015 23:05:38

 sensor trillium 0 T3N04
 add
 close sensor trillium 01/14/2015 23:05:38
 #######Next station block###############

 sta charlie2 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43 topico2
 time 01/23/2015 17:04:22
 net XI SPREE
 datalogger q330 0100000EA9C2B9C3 # 2842
 sensor trillium 0 T3S84
 add
 close sensor trillium 01/23/2015 17:04:22

 sensor sts2 0 T3N04
 add
 close sensor sts2 01/23/2015 17:04:22
```

Comment: I slimmed it down to only the necessary components. I just didn't want someone to write up a solution using line numbers as there are other entries in between. Thanks for considering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this sounds like what you want but idk how the date in your posted output became 1/23 when all of the input has date 1/14:

```
$ awk '/^time/{time=$2" "$3} /^sensor/{sensor=$1" "$2} {print} /^add/{print "close", sensor, time}' file
sta charlie 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43 topico
time 01/14/2015 23:05:38
net XI SPREE
datalogger q330 0100000EA9C2B9C3 # 2842
sensor cmg3t 0 T3S82
add
close sensor cmg3t 01/14/2015 23:05:38

sensor trillium 0 T3N04
add
close sensor trillium 01/14/2015 23:05:38
#######Next station block###############

sta charlie2 34.07335 -106.91932 1.43 topico2
time 01/14/2015 23:05:38
net XI SPREE
datalogger q330 0100000EA9C2B9C3 # 2842
sensor trillium 0 T3S84
add
close sensor trillium 01/14/2015 23:05:38

sensor sts2 0 T3N04
add
close sensor sts2 01/14/2015 23:05:38
```

Comment: Works like a charm Ed, thanks a lot! I didn't think it would be such a simple solution. I'm still relatively new to awk, and I believe I understand everything here, but if you wouldn't mind explaining the solution a bit, that would be great. I appreciate your help!

Comment: It just saves info for the lines that start with time and sensor and prints them after a line that starts with add. Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: So it takes the time value and saves $2 and $3, then grabs the sensor entries $1 & $2, prints them and appends them along with the phrase "close" after each "add" statement. Would that be a correct way of stating it what it's doing?